Simplest way in C# to defer task execution without synchronization context
Inside an async method in C#, I need to defer the execution (return the execution to the caller), and also to clear the synchronization context before proceeding with the execution.
The statement await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false); at the beginning of the method would do that, but with an average performance penalty of 15ms due to the delay.
A better way to defer and clear execution context is to check the current execution context and call Task.Yield (it keeps the execution context, if any) or Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false):
public async Task Test()
{
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current is null)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
    }
    else
    {
        await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    // Deferred code
}

Do you know if there is an easier way to defer the execution of current task (like Task.Yield does) and clear the synchronization context at same time?


Inside an async method in C#, I need to defer the execution (return the execution to the caller), and also to clear the synchronization context before proceeding with the execution.

Starting from .NET 8, you can achieve this goal by using the ConfigureAwaitOptions.ForceYielding option.

Forces an await on an already completed Task to behave as if the Task wasn't yet completed, such that the current asynchronous method will be forced to yield its execution.

Usage example:
await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(ConfigureAwaitOptions.ForceYielding);

The execution will always return to the caller immediately at the await point. In other words the caller will receive immediately the Task that represents the asynchronous operation. The continuation after the await will run invariably on a ThreadPool thread, regardless of the original SynchronizationContext.Current at the await point. ThreadPool threads don't have an ambient SynchronizationContext, so after the await the synchronization context will be effectively "cleared".
As a side note, the await Task.Delay(1); doesn't guarantee that the continuation will be asynchronous. It is theoretically possible that the OS will suspend the current thread immediately after creating and before awaiting the Task. The OS can suspend any thread at any time for a duration typically between 10 and 30 msec (demo). When the thread is resumed, the Task might have already been completed, in which case the continuation after the await will run on the same thread.

I had no idea this was added on NET 8, it's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

@RicardoRocha I wasn't aware either, until recently that I read this blog post by Stephen Cleary.
